# ¿Como hago para verificar que no se venda un articulo en cierto horario?

Tags: c#

¿Como están? 
Le vengo dando vueltas y no pude solucionarlo, tengo problemas con la lógica.
Estoy programando con C# un programa para un kiosco, la lógica que tengo hecha tiene errores. Lo que hago es tomar dos datetimes, uno con el horario desde que hora desea que no se venda ese producto y el otro datetime hasta que horario.
Si tengo la restricción de horario en el mismo día (es decir, de 19 a 22 si me funciona) pero si tengo desde las 22 hasta las 06 AM del siguiente día, no me funciona y no entiendo como hacerlo. 
¿Me podrían ayudar?
Gracias!

```
public static bool Validar(bool ActivarHoraVenta, DateTime HoraDesde, DateTime HoraHasta)
    {
        var HoraActual = DateTime.Now;
        if (!ActivarHoraVenta) return true;

        if(ActivarHoraVenta)
        {
            if(HoraDesde < HoraHasta)
            {
                if(HoraActual >= HoraDesde && HoraActual <= HoraHasta)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(HoraDesde > HoraHasta)
            {
                // Aqui debería hacer la parte que estoy preguntando
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Usas bases de datos?? dejas muy amplio en caso de ser por medio de base de datos lo que podrias hacer es que con un sp que haga la inserción validar que no se pueda vender en ese horario

Comment: Si, estoy usando base de datos, SQL.

Comment: Supongo que estas usando alguna base de datos, algunos motores permiten crear eventos que se ejecuten a determinada hora, se podria hacer un evento que a las 22:00 hs actualice una un campo poniéndolo en FALSE de los productos que no se pueden vender. Luego, a las 6:00 hs otro evento que se ejecute siempre a las 6:00 hs que lo vuelva a poner en TRUE.
Si es una tabla con muchos productos seria mejor crear una nueva tabla para indicar esto y que los productos tengan una referencia a esa tupla. (para hacer solo un UPDATE en vez de un UPDATE a todos los productos).

Answer (score -1):

Al que necesite le dejo la respuesta:

```
public static bool Validar(bool ActivarHoraVenta, DateTime HoraDesde, DateTime HoraHasta)
    {
        var horaCero = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        var horaInicioRestriccion = new TimeSpan(HoraDesde.Hour, HoraDesde.Minute, HoraDesde.Second);
        var horaFinRestriccion= new TimeSpan(HoraHasta.Hour, HoraHasta.Minute, HoraHasta.Second);

        var HoraActual = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if (!ActivarHoraVenta) return true;

        else 
        {
            if((horaInicioRestriccion < HoraActual && horaCero > HoraActual) || (horaCero < HoraActual && horaFinRestriccion > HoraActual))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```